# Different query result in main and child thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

note: The relation: `User` has many `Devices`.

Before calling the method bellow, in a Rspec test I'm creating the user with exactly 1 device.

```
def perform_stuff_in_a_thread
  user.devices.where(platform: 0) # <ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Device id: 286, user_id: 19009, token: "abcd123", platform: 0, created_at: "2015-04-21 19:55:35", updated_at: "2015-04-21 19:55:35">]>
  Thread.new do
    user.devices.where(platform: 0) # <ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
  end
end
```

Is there any catch I'm missing with ActiveRecord and threads? Why does the query inside a spawned thread doesn't work as expected?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Rails gives different threads different connections (to be precise there is a pool of database connections and any one member of the pool is only give to one thread at a time).

I'm assuming you're using some form of transactions around your specs - either the support built-in to rspec-rails or via database_cleaner. This means that the devices you've created are in an uncommitted transaction and by default this means the aren't visible to other connections (read up on transaction isolation levels if you want to know more about this), in particular the one in the thread you've spawned.

As an aside current versions of rails don't check connections created in threads in automatically - you need to do this yourself. The `with_connection` method is an easy way to do this.